# Can mypy accept annotations on inherited properties?

Tags: python, python-3.x, types, annotations, mypy

I have an odd situation, where adding an explicit type hint seems to make mypy fail.

This code validates (Python 3.6.1, mypy 0.540):

```
class BaseA:
    def __init__(self):
        self.foo: float = 1.0

class DerivedA(BaseA):
    @property
    def foo(self):
        return 2.0
```

but telling mypy what the property returns fails

```
class BaseB:
    def __init__(self):
        self.foo: float = 1.0

class DerivedB(BaseB):
    @property
    def foo(self) -> float:
        return 2.0

# error: Signature of "foo" incompatible with supertype "BaseB"
```

Related, I think, leaving off the annotation also fails with multiple inheritance, whichever combination (both, either, none) is annotated:

```
class BaseC:
    foo: float = 1.0

class MixinC:
    @property
    def foo(self):
        return 2.0

class DerivedC(MixinC, BaseC):
    pass

# error: Definition of "foo" in base class "MixinC" is incompatible with
# definition in base class "BaseC"
```

Any ideas why, or how this could be changed?

Comment: Aside from the type hinting problems, your code doesn't actually work. `self.foo: float = 1.0` is going to hit the property, but you didn't write a setter, so the property is unsettable.

Comment: True, this was an error of trying to be too clear, foo in BaseC was originally a static variable, not an instance variable, and the code functions. I didn't want to muddy the water with class  variables too, sorry.